# LibGDX InputProcessor Documentation

Tags: java, libgdx, polling, eventhandler

As the documentation on [this](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Input.html) link suggests

> Instead of polling for events, one can process all input events with
>   an InputProcessor.

though then the documentation of InputProcessor [says](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/InputProcessor.html)

> It will be called each frame before the call to
>   ApplicationListener.render().

As far as I know EventHandlers are called only when the event is fired, thus they are more efficient than polling. Why does it say that it is called each frame ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at the source code, I can see that the input processor is called in the game loop right before `render()`, but only with queued up input events that are aquired from event listeners. So behind the scenes, event listeners queue up all input events. Right before `render()` any queued events are flushed to your game's InputProcessor. If there are none, it won't get any calls.

I think your quote from the documentation is just trying to tell you at what point in the game lifecycle the input events come through to the processor.

Comment: Oh I see. So actually the key presses are not processed rightaway but when the processor is called. That is good to know. Thanks